# Why are monetary consecrations called קדשת דמים?

Tags: hekdesh

If one consecrates an animal with a blemish it is ineligible to be offered as a sacrifice. In these cases, the animal is redeemed, and the money given in exchange is applied to the for the purpose consecration. Any such consecrations that are redeemed are called קדשת דמים. I think the literal translation of that phrase is "blood sanctity." Why are they called that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the root דמה = equivalent, compensation; money, price, value; payment.

Sources:

[Klein](https://www.sefaria.org/Klein_Dictionary%2C_%D7%93%D6%B8%D6%BC%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D_%E1%B4%B5%E1%B4%B5.1?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%93%D6%B8%D6%BC%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D&with=Lexicon&lang2=en)

> דָּמִים ᴵᴵ m.n. pl. PBH money, value, price. [Prob. derived from דמה (= to be like, in the sense ‘to be equal’). cp. the related Syr. דְּמַיָּא (= price, hire), from דְּמָא (= was like, resembled).]

[Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org/Jastrow%2C_%D7%93%D6%B8%D6%BC%D7%9E%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%9D?lang=bi)

> דָּמִים, דָּמִין m. pl. , constr. דְּמֵי (דמה) equivalent, compensation; (cmp. שָׁוָה) price, value; payment. Pes. 112ᵇ do not bargain בשעה שאין לך ד׳ when thou hast no money to pay with. Kerith. 13ᵇ ד׳ וערכין the assessment of an object to be redeemed or of an object the value of which was dedicated, v. עֶרֶךְ.—Pes. 32ᵃ לפי מידה … או לפי ד׳ וכ׳ must he pay the fine according to quantity or according to value?—Kidd. I, 6 כל הנעשה ד׳ באחר whatever is used as payment for another object; expl. ib. 28ᵃ כל הנישום ד׳ וכ׳ whatever is assessed as an equivalent, i.e. an exchange is meant and not a sale for cash. Ib. 28ᵇ החליף דמי שור בפרה if he gives a cow in payment of money which he owes for an ox; a. fr.—Keth. 103ᵇ נהוג נשיאותך בד׳ Ar. conduct thy office of Nasi as something valuable (Var. in Ar., a. ed. ברָמִים).

As an aside, I heard in a shiur, why is the blessing of giving charity long life? Mida k'neged mida. If a person gives charity, which is money off his livelihood, he is effectively giving over some of his "ability to live" (extreme case, gives away his last penny to charity). Perhaps this is a deeper meaning and it would be good to find out if this is what is the real reason the term is used.

Comment: In short, דמים means "money" not "blood"

Comment: @DoubleAA Ok, is this a point of moderation that my answer was too long?

Comment: Not too long, but long enough that a short summary of the main point could help many people understand what you are getting at.

Comment: @DoubleAA Noted. Are you absolutely sure that the terms/etymology aren't related? Perhaps I am being too philosophical]